# Inconsistent in Material UI display

Tags: material-ui

I notice that in Material UI Dialog, sometimes it doesn't display the correct layout. For example:
[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

These are the same component. However, it displays different styles. The second style is the one I want it to be. It's really inconsistent. Sometimes it displays the second one, but sometimes it shows the first one. Does anyone know what's going on? I didn't override any textfield styles at all, I just override the global primary colour and font.

My textfield component:

```
<TextField 
                 error = {error.firstName? true: false}
                 label="First name" variant="outlined" 
                 name = "user.firstName"
                 value = {props.newUser.firstName}
                 onChange = {e => {
                    props.setUser((prevUser) => ({ 
                        ...prevUser, 
                        ...{firstName: e.target.value} }
                        ));
                 }}
                helperText = {error.firstName && error.firstName}
                fullWidth

                />
```

Comment: try inspecting the html to see what changes or post it here

Comment: Can you show me how you style the `TextField` component?

Comment: Updated my textfield component

Comment: @SteffanoFesta So with the first display, the `.css-md26zr-MuiInputBase-root-MuiOutlinedInput-root` is still there with the default font "Roboto". And with my second display, the field has a new class `.MuiInputBase-root`that overrides the previous one

Comment: I didn't touch any MuiInputBase css at all

Answer (score 1):

Are you currently migrating to v5? If yes, I would guess that you still have `@material-ui/core` in your bundle because it is a peer dependency of some other dependency that you have.

Try running `yarn why @material-ui/core` (or `npm ls @material-ui/core`) and check if this is the case.

You would need to upgrade the dependencies that depend on `@material-ui/core` to the specific version that depends on `@mui/material`.

Comment: Oh in this component I imported Textfield from @mui/material. Could that be the issue? Because other components that uses @material-ui/core, it has no problem

Comment: Yep it's the issue! Thank you